# Programmatically do authentication in a Duo protected application

Tags: authentication

I have an application that is protected by Duo 2FA.  I can access the application via the interactive Duo web pages, but I'd like to access the app's API in code.  How do I perform the Duo auth in code?   Note that I'm not interested in accessing Duo's API, just the app's API.  I'd like to use Python, but am open to anything.

Comment: All that's really necessary is to programmatically send a duo request. I would also like to find this out.